# How To Add Javascript To HTML Button

Tags: javascript, html

I want my aweber optin to popup on the same page when you click the button right now I am using the a href which takes you to new page but I want it that when you click the button it must popup on the same page.

Aweber gives you a Javascript or Raw HTML or Link( which is what I am using now)

I have tried to save the Javascript as a .js file a call it with a onClick event but cant get it to work.

Here is my button code as it currently works with the link and opens in new page:

```html
<div class="send-button">
<a class="cta__btn role-element leadstyle-link" 
href="MY AWEBER LINK">CLICK HERE TO APPLY &#187;</a>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```js
<div class="AW-Form-493252358"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "http://forms.aweber.com/form/58/493252358.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, "script", "aweber-wjs-pklekkdj5"));
</script>
```

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/cp67J/ it uses bootstraps modal.hope it helps

Comment: are you adding the onevent after the button has been added to the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomething(){
    // ...
}
</script>

<a href = "#" onClick="doSomething">Button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force a lightboxed AWeber form to show using 
`awf_Form_.showForm();`